# if $f(z)$ is continuous on the compact set $\Omega$, then $|f(z)|$ attains its maximum in $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

The statement in the title occurs in the proof of the corollary, of the maximum modulus principle in Steina and Shakarchi. But I haven't seen a proof of this? How would one prove this:
[image: page1]

Comment: [Extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces)

Comment: I presume the conclusion should be $=$ rather than $\le$?

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions preserve compactness, so the image of $\vert f\vert$ on $\overline\Omega$ is compact. And compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ are closed and bounded due to Heine-Borel, so they contain a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: @Vercassivelanos - this is true in $\Bbb{R}$ but is it true in $\Bbb{C}$ as well?

Comment: Yes: compactness is a topological property, and is preserved by all continuous maps between any two topological spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot @diracdeltafunk

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is constant the result is immediate, so assume that $f$ is non constant.

Since $|f|$ is continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$ (which is compact) there is some point $z^* \in \overline{\Omega}$
such that $|f(z)| \le |f(z^*)|$ for all $z \in \overline{\Omega}$.

In particular, $\sup_{z \in \Omega} |f(z)| \le \max_{z \in \overline{\Omega}} |f(z)| = |f(z^*)|$.

Since $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, we cannot have $z^* \in \Omega$ (by open mapping theorem or maximum modulus), so we must have $z^* \in \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega$.

Hence $\max_{z \in \overline{\Omega}} |f(z)| = \max_{z \in \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega} |f(z)|$.

Since $z^* \in \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega$  there are $z_n \in \Omega$ such that $z_n \to z^*$.

Since $|f(z_n)| \to |f(z^*)|$ we have $\sup_{z \in \Omega} |f(z)| \ge |f(z^*)|= \max_{z \in \overline{\Omega} \setminus \Omega} |f(z)|$ as desired.